# Trying to remember a synonym for a "fixed smile"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I remember reading this word in the writings of Anthony Burgess. I think it began with an 'r' and could also be used in a medical context when describing facial paralysis. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The word is **rictus**.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rictus) has:

> *rictus*: A fixed grimace or grin: *their faces were each frozen in a terrified rictus*

[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rictus) adds:

> A *rictus* is a frozen, fake smile. If the star of a play finds herself
>   overcome by stage fright, she might forget her lines and stand,
>   trembling, her mouth twisted into a rictus.

And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risus_sardonicus) gives the medical usage:

> *Risus sardonicus* or *rictus grin* is a highly characteristic, abnormal, sustained spasm of the facial muscles that appears to
>   produce grinning.
>
> The name of the condition, which has its roots in the Mediterranean
>   island of Sardinia, derives from the appearance of raised eyebrows and
>   an open "grin" – which can appear sardonic or malevolent to the lay
>   observer – displayed by those suffering from these muscle spasms.

Comment: I always imagine something terrible going on when I picture someone with a *rictus grin*. Like some malevolent force has frozen their face, so despite their true feelings, the people just have this mask they are stuck behind.

Answer (score -1):

You may also be looking for the slightly more colloquial phrase Stepford Smile.

Unfortunately, the only approximate definition I can find appears to be a [TVTropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StepfordSmiler):

> The Stepford Smiler is obsessed with projecting an image of wholesome happiness in order to be accepted by her peers.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's customary here to give a link to a reference, and a definition when one is available online. Otherwise your answer may get closed.

Comment: Have added a dubious source, am prepared for oblivion. Sorry about that. If it's inappropriate, I'll delete it later.

Comment: Looks good to me ... it's a gray zone. The down votes can be related to how well people think you answered the question. Given the question was asking for a word beginning with 'r' and has a well up-voted answer, it's not too surprising that you're getting down votes.